# Prove a inequality about integral and summation

Tags: integration, inequality, summation

If $f(x)$ is monotonic increasing on the interval $a\leq x < \infty$, could we prove following inequality formally?

\begin{equation}
 f(a+k) \leq \int_{a+k}^{a+k+1} f(t) dt \leq f(a+k+1)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f(a+k) \leq f(t) \leq f(a+k+1)$ for $t \in [a+k, a+k+1]$

Answer (score 0):

Write 
\begin{align}
      f(a+k)
&=    \inf\{f(u) \mid u \in [a+k,a+k+1) \} \\
&=    \int_{a+k}^{a+k+1} \inf\{f(u) \mid u \in [a+k,a+k+1) \}  dx \\
&\leq \int_{a+k}^{a+k+1} f(x)  dx \\
&\leq \int_{a+k}^{a+k+1} \sup\{f(u) \mid u \in [a+k,a+k+1) \}  dx \\
&=     f(a+k+1).
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, what is inf and sup here?

Comment: No problem! They mean "infimum" and "supremum", which are the greatest lower bound, and the least upper bound respectively. You can think of them as the min and the max.